# How to check if a user is logged in with Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, react-native, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

Using react native.

In my JSX code i threw in handling for the onLoginFound event, saying to print something if a login was found. This NEVER prints which is weird.

I then added this line thinking I could use the getCurrentAccessToken() function to check if the user is logged in.

```
alert(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null)
```

This returns true all the time though even when no one is logged in so it doesn't appear to be working.

Is there something obvious I am missing? can't believe checking if a user is logged in could be such a pain point for me to figure out.

All my code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
  LoginButton,
  AccessToken,
  GraphRequest,
  GraphRequestManager,
} = FBSDK;

export default class FBReact extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.ios.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
          Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
        </Text>
        <LoginButton
          publishPermissions={["publish_actions"]}
          onLoginFinished={
            (error, result) => {
              if (error) {
                alert("login has error: " + result.error);
              } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                alert("login is cancelled.");
              } else {
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                  (data) => {
                    alert(data.accessToken.toString());
                    let token = data.accessToken.toString();
                  }
                )
              }
            }
          }
          onLogoutFinished={() => alert("logout.")}
          onLoginFound={function(data){
            console.log("Existing login found.");
            console.log(data);
            alert("log in found");
            _this.setState({ user : data.credentials });
          }}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('FBReact', () => FBReact);
alert(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null)
```

Comment: What you get when you do `console.log(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken())` ? May be you are really logged in and you need to logout before that accesstoken become null.
In my code I did by storing something in AsyncStorage after success facebook login. Then check for that stored value later.

Comment: AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() seems to just return an Object regardless of whether I am signed in or not. Not sure if it is relevant but whenever I close the app and reopen it the login button switches back to saying "Login with Facebook" implying I get logged out automatically or something when i close the app. Just for reference, how do you use a token stored in AsyncStorage to do things with Facebook?

Comment: Basically with FacebookLogin I just need the email and some other profiles data. So i used the LoginManager https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk#requesting-additional-permissions-with-login-manager  . Once I get those user data. Either then just store those emails using AsyncStorage or any other relevant data for reference purpose or send to any server you are running for backend authentication.

Answer (score 0):

`AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()` is a promise.

You need to wait it to resolve to get the content. As follows:

```
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
  .then((tokenInfo) => {
    console.log(tokenInfo);
  });
```

Here is the source code of this method for reference:

```
/**
 * Getter for the access token that is current for the application.
 */
static getCurrentAccessToken(): Promise<?FBAccessToken> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken((tokenMap) => {
      if (tokenMap) {
        resolve(new FBAccessToken(tokenMap));
      } else {
        resolve(null);
      }
    });
  });
```